# WinRM-NTLM - the specified credentials were rejected by the server

Tags: ntlm, winrm

## **Windows host winrm configuration:**

```
Config
MaxEnvelopeSizekb = 500
MaxTimeoutms = 60000
MaxBatchItems = 32000
MaxProviderRequests = 4294967295
Client
    NetworkDelayms = 5000
    URLPrefix = wsman
    AllowUnencrypted = false
    Auth
        Basic = true
        Digest = true
        Kerberos = true
        Negotiate = true
        Certificate = true
        CredSSP = false
    DefaultPorts
        HTTP = 5985
        HTTPS = 5986
    TrustedHosts = *
Service
    RootSDDL = O:NSG:BAD:P(A;;GXGR;;;S-1-5-21-3156905383-3749233311-1980730934-64597)(A;;GA;;;BA)(A;;GR;;;IU)S:P(AU;FA;GA;;;WD)(AU;SA;GXGW;;;WD)
    MaxConcurrentOperations = 4294967295
    MaxConcurrentOperationsPerUser = 1500
    EnumerationTimeoutms = 240000
    MaxConnections = 300
    MaxPacketRetrievalTimeSeconds = 120
    AllowUnencrypted = false
    Auth
        Basic = true [Source="GPO"]
        Kerberos = true
        Negotiate = true
        Certificate = false
        CredSSP = true
        CbtHardeningLevel = Relaxed
    DefaultPorts
        HTTP = 5985
        HTTPS = 5986
    IPv4Filter = * [Source="GPO"]
    IPv6Filter = * [Source="GPO"]
    EnableCompatibilityHttpListener = false
    EnableCompatibilityHttpsListener = false
    CertificateThumbprint
    AllowRemoteAccess = true [Source="GPO"]
Winrs
    AllowRemoteShellAccess = true [Source="GPO"]
    IdleTimeout = 7200000
    MaxConcurrentUsers = 2147483647
    MaxShellRunTime = 2147483647
    MaxProcessesPerShell = 2147483647
    MaxMemoryPerShellMB = 2147483647
    MaxShellsPerUser = 2147483647
```

Connection through Kerberos is successful, but I need to connect not by fqdn, but by computer ip address.
I use this python code:

````
```
import winrm

prot = winrm.protocol.Protocol(
    endpoint = "http://192.168.1.5:5985/wsman",
    transport = "ntlm",
    username = "username@TEST.LOCAL",
    password = password,
    server_cert_validation = "ignore"
)

shell = prot.open_shell()
command = prot.run_command(shell, "ipconfig")
out, err, status = prot.get_command_output(shell, command)

print(f"Errors: {err}")
print(f"Status: {status}")
print(f"Output: {out}")
```
````

in that case i get the "InvalidCredentialsError: the specified credentials were rejected by the server"

I used different spellings of username, ip address but still getting the error